# Cumprod plus addtion on each row

Tags: r

I have two vectors

```
Returns<-c(1.0582529,1.2707149,1.301343,1.1060686,1.0943494)
Contributions <-c(1000,1250,1500,1750,2000)
```

I want to multiple the returns by the contributions +next row Contribution

so

```
Returns[1] *Contributions [1] = Result 1
Returns [2] * Result 1 + Contributions [2] =Results 2
```

etc

where the results would be

```
Results = c(1058.2529,2933.131353,5769.024454,8316.556852,11289.9178)
```

Comment: Your desired output is unclear. I'm getting `2594.738` as the second value, e.g. `Returns[1L] * Contributions[1L] * Returns[2L] + Contributions[2L]`

Comment: Sorry I should've put it as Returns[2] * (Results 1 +Contributions [2]) but adding on Contributions 2 afterwards is fine as well resulting in c(1058.2529,2594.737728,4876.643779,7143.902558,9817.925477). I can adjust my wording in the results for when the contribution happens. Either beginning of period or end

Comment: Try `Results <- numeric(length(Returns)) ; Results[1L] <- Returns[1L] * Contributions[1L] ; for(i in 2:length(Returns)) Results[i] <- Returns[i] * (Results[i - 1] + Contributions[i]) ; Results` maybe

Answer (score 0):

The answer goes out to David Arenburg. Memory pre-allocation and `for` loop.

```
Returns <- c(1.0582529, 1.2707149, 1.301343, 1.1060686, 1.0943494)
Contributions <- c(1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000)

Results <- numeric(length(Returns))
Results[1] <- Returns[1] * Contributions[1]

for (i in seq_along(Results)[-1]) {
  Results[i] <- Returns[i] * (Results[i - 1] + Contributions[i])
}

Results
# [1]  1058.253  2933.131  5769.024  8316.557 11289.918
```